# JMockit Mocking static private calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, jmockit

HOW TO MOCK `getProperty(string)` method,  the reference is a private static field using JMockit.........

```
[...]
private static LWPropertyResource props =  null;
props = LWSupportFactoryImpl.getInstance().getPropertyResource(VALIDATE_HANDLER_PROPS);
        ,
        endDate = props.getProperty("endDate");

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a mock field or mock parameter of desired type, and record the expectations you need on it:

```
@Test
public someTest(@Mocked final LWPropertyResource res)
{
    final Date endDate = new Date();

    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        res.getProperty("endDate"); result = endDate;
    }};

    // Call the code under test.
}
```